# What is the difference between .class1.class2 and .class1 .class2 in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Adding a space between two class identifier in css has a meaning?

```
.class1.class2
.class1 .class2
```

Comment: thank you, I could not find the other question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.class1.class2
```

matches element that has both classes.

```
.class1 .class2
```

matches element with class2 inside element with class1.